# Modeling a non-stationary bounded series

Tags: time-series, stationarity, percentage

I'm trying to model a time series variable that represents a percentage, strictly bounded between 0 and 1, that is also non-stationary about the mean.

**Is there a model form that is able to account for non-stationary behavior while producing forecasts within the [0,1] interval?**

I came across the following work while researching the topic which I believe could be extended to answer this particular question (just a hunch based on a quick reading):

> Park, Joon Y., and Peter CB Phillips. "[Nonlinear regressions with integrated time series.](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=105690642874776131&hl=en&as_sdt=0,33)" Econometrica 69.1 (2001): 117-161.
>
> Park, Joon Y., and Peter CB Phillips. "[Nonstationary binary choice.](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=4033766545045275192&hl=en&as_sdt=0,33)" Econometrica 68.5 (2000): 1249-1280.
>
> Hu, Ling, and Robert de Jong. [Nonstationary Censored Regression](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=5508983520189467947&hl=en&as_sdt=0,33). mimeo, Ohio State Uni, 2006.

Unfortunately, I'm unaware of any implementation (preferably in `R`) of the ML estimators discussed.

---

Per Alecos' requests, below is a plot of the series that led to this question

[image: graph]

and the de-trended series

[image: detrend]

Comment: You will have to be more descriptive about what "very non-stationary" means. Does the series exhibit seasonality-cycles (non-stationary in the mean)? Does variability seems to change, and maybe cluster? (non-stationarity in the variance)? Both? Other? The best idea would be to graph the series and upload it here -visual inspection of time series is always important.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've included an image in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Given the graph, the obvious first comments are:
1) No-intercept, or very close to zero.
2) A deterministic time trend. Start the $t$ variable at the value $0$, or $1$, and increase the index following the periodicity of the data.
3) A structural shift is detectable from 2010 onwards, that shifts the mean of the de-trended series, creating a non-zero constant term (without affecting the slope of the trend). You could include that as a dummy variable taking the value $0$ up to 2009, and the value $1$ afterwards (this is essentially a "partial" intercept).

In all cases, de-trend the data, estimating by OLS a regression of the form

$$y_t = a + bt + \gamma d_t + u_t$$

where $d_t$ is the partial intercept I mentioned previously, obtain the series

$y^* = y_t - \hat b t -\hat \gamma d_t$
and graph it. And if you want, let us know.

**ADDENDUM**
the residual graph shows traces of varying variance, but not very strong. So probably you can treat the de-trended series as variance stationary. Then estimating an ARMA model 
$$y_t = a + bt + \gamma d_t + A(L)y_t+B(L)u_t$$

where $A(L)$ and $B(L)$ are lag-polynomials, forecasts will be bounded in (0,1), since the dominant term here is the deterministic trend, and given also that the process is still at ~$0.1$. Conceptually one could wonder what will happen if this upward trend continues indefinitely: will the process hit the ceiling and remain there, or will it start to descend? But this is very closely tided to the real-world phenomenon under study. For short term prediction, this is not a problem, since again, the process has still way to go in order to approach the ceiling.

Comment: Thanks Alecos. I've included the result you requested, however, I fail to see how this answers my question, as I'm interested in ensuring any forecast remains within the [0,1] interval. This is more likely due to my poor phrasing of the problem; I've rewritten my answer to highlight that requirement, and that I'm looking for a general solution to this kind of problem.

Comment: The conventional unit root test is not applicable in case of bounded series : see the paper 
[Testing for unit roots in bounded time series](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304407613001905)

Comment: @Metrics And why should we need a unit-root test here?

Comment: @ Alecos: to check whether the bounded series is stationary or not.

Comment: @Metrics The phenomenon of the existence of a unit-root is just one of the ways that non-stationarity can be induced. In the specific series, a deterministic trend is clearly present. In theory, they could co-exist, so a unit-root test could be applied to the detrended series, but I don't see any real gain in that, since the deterministic trend is the leader here.

Answer (score 0):

If your observations are proportions $p_1, \ldots, p_T$ you can use Beta regression (GLM type) to model

$$ p_t \sim Beta(\mu_t, \phi_t),$$

where $\mu_t = g^{-1}(X_t \beta)$ is the conditional mean of the Beta distribution, and $g$ is the link function (typically, g = logit). The $\phi$ parameter is the precision and can be either set as a constant, or also modeled with covariates.  In your case a simple trend regression would already do the trick.

If you want to look into time series models, I can recommend [this very recent AoAS paper on Beta regression, ARMA models, and Google Flu data](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.3533.pdf). Very intuitive and nicely illustrated.

References

- Ferrari and Cibrari-Neto (2004): [original paper on Beta regression](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0266476042000214501) (see [here](http://www.ime.usp.br/~sferrari/beta.pdf) too)
- [vignette of the **betareg** R package](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v34/i02/paper): this nicely works together with the **strucchange** package, so you can actually answer also questions about some of the other replies re structural shifts in the data around 2010.
- Guolo and Varin (2014) and their [ARMA models for Beta regression](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.3533.pdf) (and [here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoas/1396966279) the officially published version)